# Non-member static templated method definitions in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, static-methods

Can I call a non-member static templated function from a static member function where the definition is split into header and cpp:

```
// zero.cpp

class Zero
{
    static void zero() { one(5); }
};

// one.h

template <typename T>
static void one(T& var);

// one.cpp

template <typename T>
void one(T& var) { }

// main.cpp

...

Zero::zero()

...
```

I'm having problems getting this to link, I keep getting undefined reference to the function I'm trying to define in one.cpp.

Initially I thought it was due to a problem with namespacing, but all files are now in the same namespace. Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: This is a duplicate a million times over, but SO is terrible at actually finding things. Stupid SO search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template definitions need to be visible at the point of instantiation. That is, it needs to be in the header somehow:

```
// one.hpp

template <typename T>
static void one(T& var)
{
    // definition visible in header
}
```

Though I'm not sure why you'd want it to be static.

Comment: Of course yes, I always get confused with this. I can forward declare a templated function in one header, provided the definition is still available within another header file. And you're right, no reason to be static in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to GMan's answer I would like to note that you can't make `T&` bind to an rvalue such as the integral literal `5` which is of type `int`. 5 will not bind to `int&`, but will bind to `const int&`.